# MIPS - Status register's Exception level bit

Tags: exception, mips

What exactly happens if MIPS CPU is processing an exception handler and another exception occurs? I appreciate answer that will describe exactly writes/reads of coprocessor 0 registers. Architecture x86 has double fault exception. Can be there a situation that is similar with double fault exception on MIPS?